# PHP sprintf() no replacing with argument swapping

Tags: php

The following code produces and undefined variable $s instead of "number two"

```
define("T1","one");
define("T2","two");

$test="number %2$s";

$test=sprintf($test, T1,T2);

echo $test;
```

Comment: escape the $ with \$ or use single quota

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single quotes solve your problem. Double quotes cause PHP to interpolate your '$' as a  variable.

```
<?php
define("T1","one");
define("T2","two");

$test='number %2$s';

$test=sprintf($test, T1,T2);

echo $test;
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/IZ2Om)

Comment: Ok so can I not do this in a heredoc statement as that is actually the point of this.

Comment: @user1209203: So then why aren't you using a nowdoc instead?