# Reusing Sprintf arguments or an alternative in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arguments, printf

I have a very long UNION, the below is just a snippet of the query:

```
UNION 
(
    /* Get new contact requests to you */
        SELECT r.registered, r.id, u.x_account_username, r.message AS comment, '' AS name, 'new_contact_request' AS type
            FROM x_allies r
            LEFT JOIN x_user u
            ON r.from = u.id
            WHERE r.registered BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s' AND r.to = '%s'
)
```

I have been using the **sprintf** function to insert the correct values into my query.

But, I have come across a problem.

My sprintf now looks like this..

How can I re-use the arguments within the sprintf function?

```
$query      =   sprintf($query, $c, $t, $c, $a, $c, $e, $profile_id, $profile_id, $profile_id, $tryblimp, $now, $profile_id, $c, $tryblimp, $now, $profile_id, $c, $tryblimp, $now, $profile_id, $c, $tryblimp);
```

[I have seen implementations of re-using arguments within PHP, but I can't seem to get it working. Here is what I have found already.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693417/php-sprintf-no-replacing-with-argument-swapping)

Can you help me find a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a bad practice to insert values directly into the SQL query string, because you should be really careful about parameters quoting. Otherwise this may lead to SQL injections or just SQL errors.
I would suggest you use PDO statements and [parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), something like this:

```
$query = 'Select * FROM table WHERE registered BETWEEN :begin AND :end';
$parametersValues = array(':begin' => $bedigDate, ':end' => $endDate);
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($parametersValues);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```